# Cannot get SUM() in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the SUM of a column **SnappersScore** from a table **LastResult**. However, there is nothing in the output at all. Not even an error. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Here it is:

```
<?php

mysql_connect(xxxxxx);
if (mysql_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(SnappersScore) AS TotalGoals FROM LastResult');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['TotalGoals'];

echo $sum;

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what $result contains after running the query? If it is false, an SQL error occured.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: have you run the query against database and see the result? is it giving you result you want?

Comment: I have run the query in the database and got the intended result.

Comment: TotalGoals = 0? Which when echo'd out becomes the string "" ... so you'll see nothing?

Comment: If MYSQL is depreciated, what is the equivelant command in mysqli?

Comment: OK, appreciate what you are saying CD001. How do I fix this?

Comment: For debugging purposes, just to see if that's the case `echo $row['TotalGoals'] ? "{$row['TotalGoals']} Goals" : "No goals!";` where you've currently got `echo $sum;`

Answer (score 1):

Only you can debug this, see what the error is:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(SnappersScore) AS TotalGoals FROM LastResult') or die(mysql_error());
```

I'll save you the repetitive "dont use `mysql_*`, don't use `die` in production bla bla bla" - this should point you in the right direction.

This is of course, assuming that when running `SELECT SUM(SnappersScore) AS TotalGoals FROM LastResult` in SQL works as expected.